# Which mechanism did Flame use to avoid being identified?

Tags: malware, known-vulnerabilities, apt

I got a question that says "What is the major difference in the USB propagation system used by Flame with regard to Stuxnet to prevent being identified?".

After Googling for a while, I haven't found anything about this.

Answer (score 1):

- Flame was Signed with certificate so AV get less suspicious about it.
- used many layer of obfuscation.
- used non-normal language for developing part of it(Lua used!)
- used rootkit technique to cover tracks.

Answer (score 0):

Not doing anything in most cases so that people wouldn't notice it.  Malware doesn't just magically get connected by your A/V software.  It has to be noticed in the wild by security researchers and then analyzed and a pattern to recognize it formed.  There was no such pattern for Flame and it didn't do enough to be noticed by the security community for a while.

With a malware that is potentially governmental in nature, you also can't rule out that some security researchers may have been in cahoots or convinced to keep it quiet until it could accomplish the mission it was designed for, but this isn't necessarily the case as the former is more than sufficient explanation.

Comment: I knew what you said about not doing anything, but the scope of the question is more on the technical side. Did it have something in its code to prevent the identification?

Comment: @yzT - see the first part of my answer.  It does nothing on most systems, that is something in the code that makes it hard to detect.  The only way to initially recognize malware is if it does something.  Otherwise, it can quite comfortably sit in the background without being easily noticed.  I don't think it was particularly hard to recognize compared to anything else after it was detected (by a person).